# MacBook Pro 13 inch trackpad: Makes very annoying sounds when clicked

Tags: troubleshooting, macbook

recently my trackpad on my MacBook Pro 13 inch has been making really annoying sounds when pressed. Almost like there's something (possibly sticky) under there. I do not recall ever spilling on this device and am wondering what's up. I don't want to take it apart because that voids all warranties with Apple.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you say you're still under warranty (one year, or three years with Apple Care), you can take it to an Apple Store to have it looked at.  You can make an [appointment at the Genius Bar online](http://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/).

Comment: Not sure if it's a spill or not though... 

I hope it's just hardware faults.

Comment: Worst thing they can say is no, but I've heard Apple is pretty good about making sure your equipment is still in top shape, especially if you got it so recently.

Comment: Yeah, Apple is a great company. The employees are always so cheerful.

Comment: Thank you! I just took it to the Genius Bar and they replaced it for free. :)

Yet another great experience at Apple.

Comment: Good to hear that, even if they're pretentious, they still keep your stuff in top shape.